# Does onbeforeunload event trigger for popup.html in a google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onbeforeunload

I'm writing a google chrome extension with a popup and a background page. The popup subscribes to certain events that the background generates, and I would like to unsubscribe from those events when the popup goes away. However, I don't see either of onbeforeunload or onunload events being generated from the popup. Are these events fired? If not, any ideas on how to capture popup close?

Comment: I have this exact question. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 34):

"beforeunload" is **not** fired for browser action popups. Believe me, I tried. "unload" should be fired correctly, however, so listen for that.

Actually, I have a similar system in place, that allows you to attach events using addEventListener, and they are automagically cleaned up when the unload event fires.

Here's a little tip: obviously you can't use `console.log`, because by the time the unload event fires, it's already too late. But, you can do this:

```
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

addEventListener("unload", function (event) {
    background.console.log(event.type);
}, true);
```

By using the above code, you can open up the background page's console, which should show that the unload event is fired correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the background console tip! Quite useful!

Comment: @AlexStack I reverted your edit. `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` is not equivalent - it is asynchronous.

Comment: At least with an event page and using `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()` to make a call to the background page to log something, I don't see this work for `unload` events.

Comment: @jdunning For event pages, you can try using the asynchronous `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` function, but it might not work.

Comment: @jdunning Oh, sorry, I guess the asynchronous call doesn't complete fast enough. So you'll have to keep using the old deprecated `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` function.

Comment: Thanks, that did end up working, but only by setting the handler directly on `window`, as described in my answer below.

Comment: In Google Chrome there's an option (`Preserve log`) so you can catch the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a kind of similar issue.
In my case, I've set the focus on an element which was in the popup page.
So when the popup is closed, the element lose the focus and I can catch the blur event.

Comment: This trick doesn't work for me - was really hopeful - but no go.

Answer (score 0):

If you've switched to using [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) instead of background pages in your extension, the recommended way of getting access to it is calling `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()` with a function that gets called back with the background page reference.

However, if you try to get the background page in an `onbeforeunload` handler, like this:

```
document.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {
        backgroundPage.log("unloading");
    });
});
```

The callback doesn't seem to fire before the page unloads, so that `log()` call is never made.

In a comment above, Pauan suggested using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` to get the page.  The only way I could get that to work was not to create the handler with `addEventListener()`.  Instead I had to go old school and set the handler directly on `window`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().log("unloading");
};
```

That finally got through to the background page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the messaging APIs to set up a Port between the popup and background page. You then should get a onDisconnect event in the background page when the popup goes away.

```
// popup.js
chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "popup" });
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    if (port.name === "popup") {
        port.onDisconnect.addListener(function () {
        console.log("popup has been closed");
    });
  }
});
```