# Is there an event for when a Chrome Extension popup is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've already tried window.unload, window.beforeunload, etc.
I'm looking for a way to notify my background page once the popup is closed.

Comment: Have you tried [`chrome.tabs.onRemoved`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onRemoved) or maybe [`chrome.windows.onRemoved`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onRemoved) if it counts as a window?

Comment: It doesn't count as a window.

Comment: See also: [Does onbeforeunload event trigger for popup.html in a google chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2315863/405550)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can try this. Connect to your background page with [chrome.runtime.connect](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html) (or `chrome.extension.connect` before Chrome 26) and `port.onDisconnect` will be fired in your background page when the popup is closed.

Comment: `port.onDisconnect` fires when the extension is removed/deleted not when the user stops using it, and the popup closes.

Comment: @Mudlabs actually it does fire when the popup closes.

Comment: @DmitryDavydov Hmm, it's not firing for me either.

Comment: Doesn't fire for me either, when popup closed.

Comment: FYI This use case is now broken in manifest v3 as ports will be closed automatically after some time and you'll get errors saying you're trying to connected a disconnected port object.

Comment: @EricUldall, I'm facing this and couldn't find any reliable workaround. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @ibic I have yet to find a reliable solution. :(

Answer (score 17):

It's as simple as that:

```
// popup.js
chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "popup" });
```

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    if (port.name === "popup") {
        port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
           console.log("popup has been closed")
        });
    }
});
```

Note that there are some edge cases where this method doesn't work. E.g. when having the popup open and then switching tabs by using a keyboard shortcut such as ctrl + t for example.

Answer (score 10):

Probably a hacky way, but in the popup page you can listen to

```
  window.onblur = function(){}
```

and send a message to active tab.

Comment: Unfortunately this triggers when switching app even with the popup still remaining open, but does not trigger when actually closing the popup by clicking the extension icon or current tab

Comment: On Safari Web Extension, only this way works!

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to figure out when the browser action popup was 
closed as `window.unonload` is triggered immediately when the popup finished 
loading, not when it's closed. There is a bug [crbug.com/31262](https://crbug.com/31262) for this.

Three work arounds available are [well described here](http://rethrowexception.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/google-chrome-onunload-event-when-closing-popup/). They include the `port.onDisconnect` trick and periodically polling `chrome.extension.getViews()` from either the popup or a background page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised noone mentioned this (I've tested it on Firefox Nightly and it works there):

```
window.addEventListener("pagehide", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
 });
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome 96.0.4664.110. I've also tried `visibilitychange` event but it works inconsistently. Moving back to port.onDisconnect hack.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I used for manifest V3:

Set up a connection in your popup's JavaScript file

```js
chrome.runtime.connect();
```

In background.js, use `onConnect` to listen for the event

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(()=>{
    //Your event will be fired in here
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the visibilitychange event on the document object. It works fine for me:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', MyFunction, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. Put below code in `background.js`/`eventPage.js`:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(window) {
    //handle close event
});
```

Comment: This will fire when any window or extension gets or loses focus. Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Helped with my related issue, so it's at least indirectly relevant IMHO...