# Run a Function on Extension Close with a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Quick question.

Is there a way to a run a function in a Chrome extension when its popup is closed?

e.g.

```
chrome.popup.onClose(function(){
    chrome.tabs.remove(mySpawnedTab.id)
});
```

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an event for when a Chrome Extension popup is closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798516/is-there-an-event-for-when-a-chrome-extension-popup-is-closed)

Comment: That other one answer its alright