# Is there any way to detect popup close for a Chrome Extension before the popup is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that [one can use ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798516/is-there-an-event-for-when-a-chrome-extension-popup-is-closed) to detect popup close. However, this doesn't work when there is information on the popup that I wish to persist.

For [this extension](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1913/19) I need to be able to save the textarea contents to sync storage when the popup is closed. There already is an update button which manages this, but no way to temporarily halt and save the status if the popup gets (accidentally) closed.

One way to do this is to keep storing the content on keypress, but I'd rather not hit the storage so often (especially since it's connected to some other event handlers).

Is there any way I can mimic `onbeforeunload` for a popup without being too heavy on the I/O?

Answer (score 0):

All extension pages (background page, browser action popups, etc.) share the same process and get direct script access to each other via chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage / chrome.extension.getViews, so one thing you could try is having an onbeforeunload event in your popup which grabs a handle to the background page and passes over any javascript data to the background page, and then have it do the serialization. You can even hand over a chunk of DOM by using document.adoptNode.

In general though we encourage more of a "save as you go after a few seconds of user idle" approach to writing extensions and apps, because your code can unexpectedly stop running for lots of reasons (entire browser or OS crash, loss of power, etc.). Obviously this is harder in cases where you have a big data structure to save, because you then have to start looking at how to do incremental save, etc.

Answer (score -3):

Use localStorage to save the data and setPopup to save the page see here  [Keep a chrome extension popup after close it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807441/keep-a-chrome-extension-popup-after-close-it/27892813#27892813)

Comment: > One way to do this is to keep storing the content on keypress, but I'd rather not hit the storage so often (especially since it's connected to some other event handlers).