# Keep a chrome extension popup after close it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension to have easy access to some documentation, basically it's a website in a popup.

It's working OK, but when I close the popup and I open it again, it relaunches the popup and I would like keep where the user was before closing it.

Any ideas?

------------ screenshots --------------------

[image]
[image]

So.. What I want to do is when the user open again the popup, show him the view he was watching.

Comment: You have to consider an extension popup as a website, that is to say - closing the popup then re-opening it is equivalent to hitting reload. So, that said, upon navigation you need to store the state of the popup using localStorage. Then when you load the page (popup), you retrieve the state information stored in localStorage and restore it.

Comment: I don't know how chrome storage works, so..I'll take a look tonight how store the state of the website and set it by javascript. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. It's really very easy to use. Just google `localStorage` - it works for all modern browsers, so there's no need to search for anything Chrome-centric. :)

Comment: You can also use `adoptNode` to move the popup to the background page upon closing and back to the popup upon opening. But I'm not sure if `iframe` fully supports `adoptNode` or not.

Answer (score -1):

`setPopup` is the essential code part you need to recognize.

```
 if(localStorage.Page && localStorage.Page != document.URL){
   //STORE CURRENT PAGE
    localStorage.Page = document.URL;
    //TRIM STRING
    var string = "chrome-extension://"+window.location.host+"/";
    String.prototype.ltrim = function() {
      return this.replace(string,"");
    }
    //SETPOPUP  OVERWRITES MANIFEST DATA
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
      tabId: null,          // Set the new popup for this tab.
      popup: localStorage.Page.ltrim()   // Open this html file within the popup.
    });

}else{
  localStorage.Page = document.URL;
}
```