# Event when chrome popup is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to listen to Chrome popup's closing event.
I tried listening to `onDisconnect` event as suggested **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798516/is-there-an-event-for-when-a-chrome-extension-popup-is-closed)**
:

background.js

```
  var port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "hello" });
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
    console.log("Disconnected");
  });
```

However, I get `Disconnected` every time I open the popup, not when I close it. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You were misunderstanding that answer. You're supposed to connect **from** the popup, and listen for disconnect from the background.

Comment: @Xan How do you get the reference to `port` object from the background?

Comment: A port represents one end of a 2-ended pipe. You have to listen for opening ports and establish the connection from the background.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround was:

```
  addEventListener("unload", function (event) {
    doSomethingInPopup();
  }, true);
```

Comment: (2017 update) Binding a function to the window.onunload event works for me, while the event listener does not