# Chrome extension popup close fired at wrong time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which is currently consists of a background page and a popup page. There are some initialization happens when the popup is opened. I am using DOM event

```
doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... }
```

And the behaviour is correct. 
The issue is when closing the popup. Since chrome popup does not throw `unload` event I am using what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801294/2474269). Here is my code

**popup.js**

```
bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
bgPageManager = bgPage.manager(); // This is the exposed api from bg page
bgPageManager.init(chrome.runtime.connect({
    name: 'P1'
}));
```

Here connecting to the runtime and sending the port to background page so that it can listen to `onDisconnect` event.

**Background.js**

```
function init(port) {
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
        // Clean up happens here
        stateManager.unregister();
    });
}
```

This works as well.

But the issue is, this `onDisconnect` **getting fired when the popup is getting opened, not when it is getting closed**

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port) for `onDisconnect` event is

> An object which allows the addition and removal of listeners for a Chrome event.

Which is not every helpful ;)

So is there anything wrong I am doing, or any way when I can detect the popup close?

Comment: Not enough code here to see a coherent picture. What's `bgPageManager`? What's listening to `onConnect`?

Comment: @Xan: added description about `bgPageManager`. And there is no `onConnect` for `Port`. You can check it here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's something listening to `chrome.runtime.onConnect` in the popup page (from your comment, doesn't seem so), `chrome.runtime.connect()` will return a Port that immediately closes (as no-one was willing to listen).

You're definitely making it more difficult than it should be with involving `getBackgroundPage` though. The popup can initiate the port itself. All you need to do is:

```
// popup code
var bgPort = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "P1"});

// background code
var popupPort;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  if(port.name == "P1") {
    popupPort = port;
    popupPort.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
      /* Clean up happens here */
    });
  }
});
```

In case you want to preserve what you already have, the minimal code to put into the popup is this:

```
var bgPort;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  if(port.name == "P1") {
    bgPort = port;
  }
});
```

Note that in all cases you need to keep a reference to the Port object on both sides. If the garbage collector collects it, the port will be disconnected.

Finally, a port name is optional; if it's the only port you use, you can drop the code that sets/checks the name.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I did not get the idea that `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` are thrown on two different objects. Now it makes sense. Thank you. I need `getBackgroundPage` since my popup page uses few APIs which are in backgroundPage and are required to hold state across the lifetime.

Comment: I always dislike `getBackgroundPage` for very tight code coupling. Using messaging/`chrome.storage` allows for more flexibility.