# Chrome extension: detect when popup window closes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup

For my chrome extension, I want to perform an action when the browserAction popup window closes. I understand that there no built-in events are triggered when this happens. I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801294/1927589) to open a connection with the background script, and then use the connection's `port.onDisconnect` event to detect that the popup window is closing.

However, when the popup window closes, I see the following error in the Developer Console for the background script:

```
(BLESSED_EXTENSION context for glkehflnlfekdijfhacccflbffbjhgbd) extensions::messaging:102: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy_' of undefined{TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy_' of undefined
   at PortImpl.destroy_ (extensions::messaging:102:37)
   at dispatchOnDisconnect (extensions::messaging:322:29)}
```

The scripts that I use are detailed below.

Can you see where I am going wrong?

---

manifest.json

```
{ "manifest_version": 2

, "name": "Detect when popup closes"
, "version": "0.1"

, "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "popup.png"
  , "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }

, "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect()
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (externalPort) {
  externalPort.onDisconnect = function () {
    try { 
      var ignoreError = chrome.runtime.lastError
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("onDisconnect")
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: The suggestion was to detect the event in background script. The port is disconnected *because* the popup was destroyed so there are no event listeners left to be invoked on port disconnection.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've rewritten my bare-bones extension to use `port.onDisconnect` in the background script, as you suggest. However, this merely displaces the error to the moment when the popup window closes.

Comment: The error in this case is documented and may be ignored by simple assignment `var ignoreError = chrome.runtime.lastError`. The important thing is that the disconnect listener will actually fire.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've added the assignment that you suggested, but I doubt that I have put it in the right place. Perhaps the disconnect listener fires, but the error prevents me from getting it to do anything useful.

Comment: @JamesNewton I rolled back your "SOLVED" edit; in future, please post your own solution (if it's appropriate) as a separate answer - self-answering is absolutely okay, but mixing answers into questions is not. Also, there's no need to tag your question as solved in the title (the fact that there is an accepted answer is enough).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onDisconnect` is not an assignable property.
It's an object that provides `addListener` method to register a callback:

```js
externalPort.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
    var ignoreError = chrome.runtime.lastError;
    console.log("onDisconnect");
});
```

Comment: I would also recommend saving `externalPort` to a variable in the outside scope; I think otherwise it risks garbage-collection.

Comment: Yes, but only to modify the port's behavior later. The listener itself is registered in the browser internals so it'll stay.

Comment: How do you get `.onDisconnect` to fire when the popup closes? Whenever I implement it, it only fires when the actual extension is uninstalled.

Comment: It should be in the background page.

Comment: Ok sweet! I was trying to setup a message port between my `popup.js` and `content script`.  But you have to pass through `background.js`, like it's the post office and `popup.js` and `content script` are two people trying to send a letter, Yes?

Comment: Content script should also work. I meant onDisconnect shouldn't be in the popup itself.

Comment: Maybe it's an execution time/order problem then?

Comment: Maybe. Why not.

Comment: @wOxxOm is it possible to place the onDisconnect listener in the Content Script instead of in `background.js`? I tried, but could not get it to work. It would save me having to create another script to inject, as the method i wish to run when closing the popup resides inside the Content Script.

Comment: Sure. Simply use chrome.**tabs**.connect with a tab id in the popup.

Answer (score 13):

For reference, here's the working version of the background.js script:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (externalPort) {
  externalPort.onDisconnect.addListener(function () {
    console.log("onDisconnect")
    // Do stuff that should happen when popup window closes here
  })

  console.log("onConnect")
})
```