# Chrome extension onClose (onunload) event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to catch extension close event with react's componentWillUnmount, but it's not invoke. Is there a React method that can be used to handle extension popup close event?

Comment: When the popup closes, its execution context is immediately destroyed so you can't rely on any code being executed. You can detect this event from your background script though - your popup should open a *port* via chrome.runtime.connect and the [background script should add onConnect and onDisconnect listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756934).