# Chrome extension - event to notify popup that it's going to be closed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm trying to save the popup state and I can't figure out how the popup **itself** would know right before it happens? All the solutions found here are about to notifying background not popup itself.

Thanks

Comment: The browser closes it unconditionally so no. You should autosave the state to storage right after it's changed to prevent data loss.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry I don't understand you. How to do it technically?

Comment: You should constantly listen to any changes and save each new data or info to storage like wOxxOm said. What is the exact data than you need to save?

Comment: @PredatorIWD Ah, okay. So the only solution is to store data every time they changed? Hm it could be tricky because I want to restore the whole popup UI and data: which tab is selected, which data is showing right now and which state those data have.

Comment: You can save each individual data then and fill it up on the next popup load.

Comment: @PredatorIWD Yes I can but I thought there is more natural way to do it - exactly *before* popup closed. And I really don't understand why there is no such event.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15798516/6908282