# persisting data in chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

Is there any `callbacks` when we click outside of chrome plugin, I want the data to persist which user has typed in but when the user clicks outside of the plugin the fields which user typed is lost, How would I persist that typed data before the user clicks outside of the plugin.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of chrome plugin"? Is it a popup?

Comment: Yes it is a popup

Comment: Add an event to listen for every change in any of the fields and store the data inside `chrome.storage`.

Comment: @PredatorIWD , then i have to place a lot of event listener like i have 10 text fields so i have put 10 event listener for each of them for 'keyup'
I find this to be helpful but it doesn't work for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798516/is-there-an-event-for-when-a-chrome-extension-popup-is-closed