# What's the difference of these two javascript usage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
var win = window.open('cover.html','','height=50,width=150,titlebar=no,toolbar=no');
win.onbeforeunload = function(){ updateIcon();};
```

**V.S.**

```
chrome.windows.create(
  { 
    url: "cover.html", 
    type: "popup", 
    width: 150,
    height: 50 
  }, 
  function(win)
  { win.onbeforeunload = function(){ updateIcon();};  } 
 );
```

The function updateIcon() is not called in chrome api version. I wonder why.  Both pieces of code are tested on ubuntu linux.

Comment: According to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create, the `win` parameter in the callback is a Window object described on that page, instead of the JavaScript `window` object. You can use `chrome.extension.getViews` (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews) to get the JavaScript `window` object if you create the popup with the second snippet.

Comment: thanks, but chrome.extension.getViews does not work. The solution I found is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315863/does-onbeforeunload-event-trigger-for-popup-html-in-a-google-chrome-extension

Answer (score 1):

As helpfully explained in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858613/whats-the-difference-of-these-two-javascript-usage#comment22571869_15858613):

`chrome.windows.create` returns a different type of window: the Chrome API [Window object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window). It does not give you access to the `window` object of the opened document.

If you need to detect when a window is closed from the opening side, you can listen to [`chrome.windows.onRemoved` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onRemoved) and compare window ID to the one you got from `create`.

If you are determined to hook into the `unload` event of the document, you can do so from the `cover.html`'s code

You can use `chrome.extensions.getViews` - but note that you must query for a `type : "tab"` and **not `"popup"`** - the latter only refers to [Browser/Page Action popups](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), not regular pages opened in a popup-type window. I know it's confusing.

You mention yourself that you found a solution to signal closing to the background page [using `runtime.getBackgroundPage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3840852/934239). As one alternative method, I can offer [opening a Port](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) to the background page - which can then listen to the disconnect event on that port which will fire when the window closes.