# Listen when extension popup page closes in Crossrider

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crossrider

I need to know when the crossrider's extension closes so I can throw some message in the background. It was easy on the other way around

```
appAPI.ready(function() {

}
```

This is what I'm using on `popup.html` to determine if the extension is opened. So what I need is something like `appAPI.close(function() {})` but I can't find it on the Crossrider's doc http://docs.crossrider.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to monitor "popup page close" event, just listen to `unload` event for popup page.

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
    // Your logic here
}, false);
```

Please be aware you can't use `console.log` in the function, since by the time the unload event fires it is already too late. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315863/does-onbeforeunload-event-trigger-for-popup-html-in-a-google-chrome-extension) for more details.