# Chrome sync storage not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to save some info a user enters on a chrome extension popup. However, when I try to save the data using `chrome.storage.sync.set` the callback never happens. I don't know why it isn't saving.

```
function saveNotebook () {
    myNotebook.lastVisited = Date.now();
    var jsonfile = {};
    jsonfile[notebookURL] = myNotebook;
    // jsonfile[notebookURL] = JSON.stringify(myNotebook);
    chrome.storage.sync.set(jsonfile, function () {
        if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
            background.console.log('An error occurred: ' + chrome.extension.lastError.message);
        }
        background.console.log("Storing jsonfile: ", jsonfile);
        background.console.log("Url for storage: ", notebookURL);
    });

}

function getAllNotesForSite(notebookURL){
    background.console.log("Retrieving storage for url: ",notebookURL);
    chrome.storage.sync.get(notebookURL, function (noteBook){
        background.console.log("Notebook Contents: ", noteBook);
        if (Object.keys(noteBook).length === 0){
            background.console.log("Notebook is empty");
            myNotebook = {
                lastVisited: "",
                notes: {}
            }
            var date = new Date();
            var noteId = "" + (date.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ (date.getDate());
            createNewNote(noteId);
            currentNoteId = noteId;
        }else {
            myNotebook = noteBook;
            document.getElementById("last-visited").textValue = myNotebook.lastVisited;
            for (var note in myNotebook.notes){
                createNewNote(note.dateCreated);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

background.console is my background page ( i think it's legal).
Here is my manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "WebNotes",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Annotate specific webpages or domains for later visits",
    /*"icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },*/
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["bg.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage"
     ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "WebNotes",
        /*"default_icon": "icon_19.png",*/
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `background.console`? What's your `manifest.json`? Is there any error info?

Comment: @HaibaraAi I am not getting any errors. The callback for chrome.storage.sync.set just never gets called.

Comment: @p1g1n What is `background.console.log` ? add the code of that function too please

Comment: 1 - How do you define myNotebook? and notebookURL?
2 - you generally calls the function? How?
3 - Remove your background in line background.console.log.

Comment: If all values are defined correctly then the function (saveNotebook) should work. [Result](https://pp.vk.me/c631516/v631516314/2c96d/HgPAHiMVauI.jpg)

Comment: `background.consol.log` is the background page for the extension and is defined as `background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();`  

The saveNotebook function is called when the page closes
    `addEventListener('unload', function () {
        background.console.log("Unloading page");
        saveCurrentNote();
        saveNotebook();
    });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does onbeforeunload event trigger for popup.html in a google chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315863/does-onbeforeunload-event-trigger-for-popup-html-in-a-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: I got it working. The problem was that my save function was in the popup script and not in the background script. Once I moved it to the background it was successful.